# Rails 6: Files with special characters in the name crash app when accessing amazon S3 with active storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6

I am uploading to amazon S3 using active storage in a rails 6 web app.  The web app works fine until I upload a file with special characters and then the app crashes when I try and read that file.

I understand that Amazon doesn't accept special characters but I am not sure how to convert the filenames before uploading... From searching forums it seems you can sanitize the filename but I'm not sure where this code would go?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :rename_filename

  def rename_filename
    if active_storage_object.attached?
      active_storage_object.blob.update(filename: "filename.#{active_storage_object.filename.extension}")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Am I right in thinking this renames the file to the name that active storage gives the file?